# What is add() in this tutorial using Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynctaskloader

i am newbie in android and i am following this [tutorial](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/android-custom-adapter-listview-with-listfragment-and-loadermanager-inside-fragmentactivity/#comment-2536)

```
public void setData(List<Model> data) {
        clear();
        if (data != null) {
            for (Model appEntry : data) {
                add(appEntry);
            }
        }
    }
```

i am getting error on add(appEntry)line:                                                The method add(Location) is undefined for the type LocationListAdapter
while **LocationListAdapter** is my class name that extends from   **BaseAdapter**

Answer (score 0):

You should extend your LocationListAdapter to ArrayAdapter instead of BaseADapter

Comment: It depends on how BaseAdapter is implemented.

Comment: i have added code of extends ArrayAdapter<LocationListAdapter>  but it still gives me error at add()  line   ERROR :                       The method add(Location) is undefined for the type LocationListAdapter